# How to set export PATH="$HOME/neovim/bin:$PATH" automatically

Tags: path

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 5 and I had to build from source to get the latest stable version. The program built successfully and I'm able to run it just fine. However whenever I open a new terminal I have to run the command `export PATH="$HOME/neovim/bin:$PATH"`before I can use the program as normal. How can I set my terminal to automatically run this command when I open it, without having to type it in manually. Please explain it as if I'm a completely new user. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the shell that you are using but if it is `bash` then as said by @Friendrich you can add at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file the following line:

```
export PATH="$HOME/Neovim/bin:$PATH"
```

And reboot your system.